# Issue while using inner join with sum

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, inner-join

I have two (2) tables:
**ps_wk_mp_seller_transaction_history**

[image]
And **ps_wk_mp_seller_order_status**

[image]

I want to totalize **seller_amount** only if **current_state** = 5

For that I have written this:

```
select sum(seller_amount) as seller_amount
from ps_wk_mp_seller_transaction_history th inner join 
     ps_wk_mp_seller_order_status os
     on os.id_order = th.id_transaction and
        os.current_state = 5 and
        th.id_customer_seller = 2;
```

For id_customer_seller=2 I get this **4984.020000 (4950+34.02)** and it is exact

But I get **25.848000** instead of NULL for id_customer_seller=5

Can someone help me?

May be you can test yourself, this the code: https://github.com/kulturman/fakerepo

Comment: The last predicate of the `ON` clause, `and th.id_customer_seller=?`, should filter out all records for the case of `id_customer_seller=5`. I cannot therefore see how you could possibly get `25.848` as a result in this case. Can you setup a mock-up that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: May be you can test yourself, this the code: https://github.com/kulturman/fakerepo

Comment: Your dB design looks flawed or at least not working for what you want to achieve. Run a query where you select * and only join on id_order and id_transaction and you will get six rows covering all combinations of seller and state meaning you can never get null from your original query since at least one combination of rows will always be selected for any valid combination of state and seller

Comment: The implication from your question is that you ***expect*** the first order status row to associate with the first two transaction rows, and the second order status row to associate to the last transaction row.  Your query, however, associates ***both*** order status rows to all three transaction rows.  *(Just like @JoakimDanielson says, that yields 6 combinations.)*  So, my question to you is ***why*** do you think that *only* the second order status row is associated to the last transaction row?  *(Which is the only way I can see that you expect a NULL in your results.)*

Comment: his issue is that `id_transaction` is same for current_state 5 and 14 and that is why `id_customer_seller` will not be null

Answer (score 0):

First of all your records have some logic issue,  `id_transaction` have tow transactions with same `id_transaction` but different amount and different `state` ! so transaction with id `41`  having state `5`  and that why customer `5` will not be null because 41 is in state 5.

To fix this

transaction id must be unique id for every transaction in order to differentiate between transaction state and amount

the query should be like this

```
select sum(seller_amount) as seller_amount
from ps_wk_mp_seller_transaction_history th 
left join ps_wk_mp_seller_order_status os 
  on os.id_order=th.id_transaction
where 
  th.id_customer_seller = 2
  and  os.current_state=5
```

working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/906d3e/7)

Comment: OP's issue derives when query `id_customer_seller=5` and he/she expects `NULL`. But your point is correct that `id_transaction` covers `os.current_state=5` for both sellers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the schema is not mine. I am trying to customize a prestashop third party module. It's a market place, when a customer place an order which contains two sellers' products the module will create two "ps_wk_mp_seller_order_status" rows. Do you see what I mean?